# How to control document do not get or add additional property in loopbak?

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs, loopback

I have a registration model in `loopback` over `mongodb` with fallowing properties:

```
"properties": {
    "Fname": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "Lname": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "phone": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "date": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "time": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  }
```

in application I post some additional data with model required data, for controlling and processing in server side:

```
submitForm() {

    let headers = new Headers(
      {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let data = JSON.stringify({
      Fname: this.form.Fname,
      Lname: this.form.Lname,
      phone: this.form.phone,
      time: this.form.time,
      date: this.form.date,
      uid: this.form.uid
    });
    //console.log(data);

    let url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/registrations';

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(url, data, options)
        .toPromise()
        .then((response) => {
          console.log('API Response : ', response.status);
          resolve(response.json());
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('API Error : ', error.status);
          console.error('API Error : ', JSON.stringify(error));
          reject(error.json());
        });
    });
  }
```

In server side I have this code:

```
 Registration.observe('before save', function (ctx, next) {
        if (ctx.instance) {
            // When Create (POST)
            // ctx.instance have the json properties
            console.log("Triggers when create");
            if (checkUID(ctx.instance) ==200 ){
                console.log('ok');
            }
        } else {
            // When Update (UPDATE)
            // ctx.data have the json properties
            console.log("Triggers when update");
        }
        next();
    });
```

but after successfully registration I saw that `uid` that was added into document and regardless to model's properties, document contains addition properties.

```
{
    "Fname": "Eram",
    "Lname": "SA",
    "phone": "1234567890",
    "date": "2017/10/06",
    "time": "17:37:46",
    "id": "59d78e3f5e5e6704205038aa",
    "uid": "38bc3241a43073a7b40d186f24923cc5"
  },
```

Comment: you have put everything as required true try and make them false depending upon your requirement

Comment: @RahulSingh Thanks, you mean if `"required": false` is enough to control properties, and prevention of adding new properties?

Comment: @RahulSingh no it is not related. there should be something to control undefined properties injection. to keep prevention of  model structure.